# react-bootstrap-typeahead error: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to use react-bootstrap-typeahead in a project.
It works as expected when i try it out in an online sandbox (I can expand the drop down and make a selection). When i try to use it in my project, the component is rendered, but clicking on it crashes the page with an error:

```
react-dom.development.js:24447 Uncaught Error: flushSync was called from inside a lifecycle method. It cannot be called when React is already rendering.
```

Below is the test component i am trying to render which i took from another stack overflow post

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

const MyTypeahead= () => {
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
return (
<div>
  <Typeahead
    id="basic-typeahead-example"
    labelKey="state"
    onChange={setSelected}
    options={[
      { state: 'AL' },
      { state: 'AK' },
      { state: 'AZ' },
      { state: 'AR' },
      { state: 'CA' },
    ]}
    placeholder="Choose a state..."
    selected={selected}
  />
</div>
);
};
export default MyTypeahead;
```

What's missing? I have a feeling there is some sort of a big gap in my understanding of state management.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass useState-update function directly in onChange. Instead write a callback and pass it in. Also, in your case, you don't need to use objects in options, just use plain strings:

```
const MyTypeahead = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (selected) => setSelected(selected);
  return (
    <div>
      <Typeahead
        id="basic-typeahead-example"
        labelKey="state"
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA"]}
        placeholder="Choose a state..."
        selected={selected}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyTypeahead;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-pare-33v6oh

Regarding flushSync - it's a known issue in the repository:

https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/715

Even though the error message is shown, the typeahead component seems to work as it should. I would suggest to ignore this error message until it is been fixed.

Comment: Hi,  this problem still persists right?